# how to play sdp file in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, sdp

I am using following code to play video for .3gp format and it works fine but I am facing problem while playing .sdp url.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("rtsp://stream.the.sk/live/musicbox/musicbox-3m.3gp"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

I need to play `rtsp://ss1c6.idc.mundu.tv:554/prf0/cid_29.sdp` format but it not work. Please help me. I tried to play it with **VLC** and **MX Player**.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Now I'm facing the similar problem. If you find solution, please share here.

Comment: @Dhasneem No i didnt solve it. I use 3gp format at the end.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Prince for your quick response.

Comment: @Dhasneem you are welcome. If you find any solution then you can post your answer.

Comment: Sure.. Now I'm searching only

Comment: @Prince Did you solved your problem?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in onCreate function. It will work i think.

```
VideoView view=new VideoView(this);
setContentView(view);
view.setMediaController(mediaController);

view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://ss1c6.idc.mundu.tv:554/prf0/cid_29.sdp"));
view.start();
```

Comment: Hello thank you for reply. But Video not playing using your code. It will display "Sorry this video cannot be played".